# getting the current user role in wordpress WITHOUT using the wordpress API

Tags: wordpress

I am getting the currently logged-in-wordpress-user-name from the wordpress authentication cookie ( without loading wordpress )

But I need to be able to get the userrole too, (especially the userrole) As far as I know, cookie does not store that info!

So I need to use straight PHP and mySQL functions ( plus the 2 key tables  wp_users and wp_usermeta ).

What is the key information I need to pull this off?

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to find the problem? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Comment: With all due respect, this is a good question. And the answers came very quickly and nicely. I see what you are trying to say, but it is not applicable here.

Comment: When you hover over the "downvote" arrow, the first reason for downvoting is "This answer does not show any research effort" - which applies to your question. Receiving answers is no indication of the quality of a question, I've seen questions closed for being so poor but still have answers... some low-rep users don't know & follow the site guidelines (or are fishing for rep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wp_logged_in_* cookie does store the username, so you could do direct SQL query on the db:

```
$username = 'username'; // get this val from the cookie

"SELECT * FROM 'wp_users' WHERE user_login = $username"
```

This will give you the entire row including `ID`, which you can use to query the usermeta table:

```
$theID = n; // this should be ID from your query, and it's an integer
"SELECT * FROM 'wp_usermeta' WHERE user_id = $theID"
```

This second query will give you all the meta related to the user ID.

Answer (score 1):

Find the user_id by selecting it in the wp_users

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_users` WHERE user_login = "[currently logged-in-wordpress-user-name]"
```

Then, use the "ID" to retrieve the user data in wp_usermeta

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `user_id` = "[ID]"
```